# How to conditionally extract data from column based on value from other columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to extract data from column `c` in another data frame only if corresponding values from variables `a` and `b` are greater than 4. For example, for respondent ID 001, `a_1` and `b_1` are not both greater than 4, so it would return NA. But `a_3` and `b_3` are both greater than 4, so it would return the corresponding `c_3` value (i.e., "b").

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c("001", "002", "003"),
  a_1 = c(2, 5, 7),
  a_2 = c(7, 3, 2),
  a_3 = c(5, 5, 7),
  b_1 = c(1, 7, 3),
  b_2 = c(3, 3, 5),
  b_3 = c(5, 7, 7),
  c_1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
  c_2 = c("c", "a", "a"),
  c_3 = c("b", "a", "c")
)
```

Desire output

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c("001", "002", "003"),
  c_1 = c(NA, "b", NA),
  c_2 = c(NA, NA, NA),
  c_3 = c("b", "a", "c")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution with `if_else` + `if_all`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(across(c_1:c_3, ~ if_else(
           if_all(ends_with(sub('c', '', cur_column())), `>`, 4), .x, NA
         )), .keep = "unused")

#    ID  c_1  c_2 c_3
# 1 001 <NA> <NA>   b
# 2 002    b <NA>   a
# 3 003 <NA> <NA>   c
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R:

```
nms <- names(data)
dat_c <- data[,grep('^c', nms)]
is.na(dat_c) <- data[,grep('^a', nms)] <= 4 | data[,grep('^b', nms)] <= 4
dat_c
   c_1  c_2 c_3
1 <NA> <NA>   b
2    b <NA>   a
3 <NA> <NA>   c
```

---

```
d <- reshape(data, -1, dir = 'long', idvar = 1, sep = '_')
is.na(d$c) <- d$a <= 4 | d$b <= 4
reshape(d)[names(data)[startsWith(names(data),'c')]]

     c_1  c_2 c_3
1.1 <NA> <NA>   b
2.1    b <NA>   a
3.1 <NA> <NA>   c
```

---

```
data %>%
   pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c(".value","name"), names_sep = "_") %>%
   mutate(value = ifelse(a > 4 & b > 4, c, NA), .keep = 'unused') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_prefix = 'c_')

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  ID    c_1   c_2   c_3  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 001   NA    NA    b    
2 002   b     NA    a    
3 003   NA    NA    c
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a more flexible answer. If you want to add more columns to check just change the query line. This line builds a logical matrix representing the points that are greater than 4 in both A and B.

```
query <- (data[,2:4] > 4) & (data[,5:7] > 4)
result <- data[,8:10]
result[!query] <- NA
print(result)

   c_1  c_2 c_3
1 <NA> <NA>   b
2    b <NA>   a
3 <NA> <NA>   c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data <- data[, c("respondent_ID", "c_1", "c_2", "c_3")]
new_data[, "c_1"] <- as.character(ifelse(data[, "a_1"] > 4 & data[, "b_1"] > 4, data[, "c_1"], NA))
new_data[, "c_2"] <- as.character(ifelse(data[, "a_2"] > 4 & data[, "b_2"] > 4, data[, "c_2"], NA))
new_data[, "c_3"] <- as.character(ifelse(data[, "a_3"] > 4 & data[, "b_3"] > 4, data[, "c_3"], NA))
```

Comment: If there are `c_1`, `c_2`, ..., to `c_100`, do you mean that we need to repeat the same code 100 times ?

Comment: The question did not specify that the code has to be scalable